Quoting a definition
First, I'd like to inquire as to whether or not it is indeed the case that whether or not to capitalize the first letter is a matter of personal preference when quoting a definition.
Secondly, I'd like to know whether or not one should include the period in a definition when quoting it. Believe it or not, I was unaware until today that every definition has a period at the end of it; they're not complete sentences, so I always assumed that no definition has a period.

Can you give an example of the sort of context you are thinking of?

"I was unaware until today that every definition has a period at the end of it" - who told you this? I don't believe it's true in general.

I'm about to delete this question, actually. Embarrassingly enough, I've never taken a look at a definition that is not the immediate result of a Google search, and only today did I ever bother to notice that such "definitions" have a period. I can't help but kind of laugh at myself now.

On another note, I'm also just now coming to the realization that the reason as to why this question is an example of a bad question is twofold: the title does not entail a specific enough question, and this "question" is in fact two questions.

A definition is an expression that conveys the meaning or meanings of a term, and whether it should be followed by a period depends on its syntactic form and context, and on stylistic considerations.

When you quote something you usually keep its original form verbatim. If it's capitalized, do that in the quote.

@PaulTanenbaum I think the period might be a moot point now since it was completely based on a misunderstanding which was the result of me relying on the featured snippet  from Google searches for all my definitions, unless what you're getting at actually entails an explanation as to why the featured snippet always uses a period and most other sources of definitions don't. My impressions is that the featured snippet's uniqueness in that regard is the result of a stylistic decision.

I'd like to give my thanks to everyone for forgiving the improper title and the fact that I asked two questions instead of one. I will be more careful in the future.

@SimonM It's ok, really to ask a couple of related sub-questions. And the title does not have to be a whole grammatical question. There must be a whole identifiable question there, of course, but it doesn't have to necessarily be whole and explicit in the title.

@Araucaria-Him I'm referring to the vagueness of the title, not the fact that it's not a complete thought/sentence. It doesn't entail a specific enough question that users can infer without reading the body of the question. For a simple post like this one, I definitely could have come up with a title that makes it extremely clear what my two specific concerns are.

Personal preference be damned. The Oxford dictionary capitalizes the first letter in a definition, so in my book "that's the way it should be done."
For quoting a definition, either quote it as is, or employ artistic license feeling free to paraphrase and punctuate at will.
